# PHP Posting an array from a form is not working

Tags: php

I have some checkboxes with printed values according to the database which are working fine.
When I submit the form it gives me an error saying that the variable which I posted from the checkboxes array is not defined and that way I cant insert the values in the database.[image: This is the error]

The PHP code to post the array and insert in the database:

```
//The posts above don't matter because the first query works just fine

$candCurso     = $_POST['curso'];

$query = "INSERT INTO tbl_candidatos(cand_nome, cand_datanasc, cand_nac, cand_nat, cand_gen, cand_morada, cand_codpost, cand_cidade, cand_email, cand_telefone, cand_telemovel, cand_tipodoc, cand_ndoc, cand_valdoc, cand_nif, cand_hablit, cand_sitprof, cand_grau, cand_instgrau, cand_datagrau, cand_instfunc, datainsc) VALUES ('$candNome','$candDataNasc','$candNac','$candNat','$candGen','$candMorada' ,'$candCodPost','$candCidade','$candEmail','$candTelefone','$candTelemovel','$candTipoDoc','$candNDoc','$candValDoc', '$candNif','$candHabLit','$candSitProf','$candGrau','$candInstGrau', ' $candDataGrau','$candInstFunc', '$dins')";
$result = mysqli_query($link, $query); // Executa a instrução MYSQL

if($result){
    echo "<script>alert('I entered the result if');</script>";
    $lastID = mysqli_insert_id($link);
        foreach($candCurso as $value) {
            echo "<script>alert('I entered the foreach if');</script>";
            $data = date('Y-m-d');
            $sql = "INSERT INTO tbl_professor_curso(cand_id, cur_id, data_admissao) VALUES ($lastID, '$value', '$data')";
            $rr = mysqli_query($link, $sql); // Executa a instrução
        }
```

The code doesn't run the foreach statement because of the variable **$candCurso**.
The form:

```
<!-- Message -->
<div class="col-md-12">
    <!-- Form Group -->
    <div class="form-group">
    <label for="form_message">Select *</label>
    <?php
        $cursos = getCursos($link);
        foreach ($cursos as $curso): ?>
        <div class="checkbox">
            <label >
                <input type="checkbox" class="form-control" name="curso[]" value="<?= $curso['cur_id'] ?>"> <?= $curso['cur_nome'] ?>
            </label>
        </div>
    <?php
        endforeach;
    ?>
    </div><!-- /End Form Group -->
</div><!-- /End Message -->
```

Any help is appreciated as I'm looking to fix this for hours.

Comment: What is in `$_POST` when you submit the form?

Comment: [curso=] => Array ( [0] => 1 [1] => 3 ), it actually posts the array but doesnt enter the foreach statement

Comment: Maybe your code breaks before ```foreach``` statement? What about your INSERT query? Do you get ```$result``` and ```$lastID``` variables?

Comment: Already solved it mate, thank you anyways.